# ruby-prof says Ruby increment operator (+=) takes 25 seconds

Tags: ruby, performance, ruby-prof

I'm trying to profile some Ruby code I wrote using `ruby-prof` gem and see that basic operations like `i += 1` (listed as `Fixnum#+` in the table below) take over 24 seconds to run (in this particular test, the operation is performed 2,199,978 times). Is this normal?

```
Thread 582936

%Total   %Self   Total   Self  Wait  Child       Calls              Name

                 203.93  81.72   0.00  122.21    100001/100001    InputFile#parse
46.96%   18.82%  203.93  81.72   0.00  122.21    100001           InputFile#split_on_semicolon
                  24.59  24.59   0.00    0.00   2199978/3200094   Fixnum#+
                  16.02  16.02   0.00    0.00    100001/399998    String#split
                  14.72  14.72   0.00    0.00    999990/999991    String#[]
                  13.12  13.12   0.00    0.00   1199988/1199990   Fixnum#<
                  10.97  10.97   0.00    0.00    999990/2239978   String#empty?
                  10.49  10.49   0.00    0.00   1199988/1199988   String#<<
                   9.75   9.75   0.00    0.00   1199988/1200074   Array#[]
                   7.77   7.77   0.00    0.00    999990/999990    String#eql?
                   6.76   6.76   0.00    0.00    599994/599994    Fixnum#-
                   4.62   4.62   0.00    0.00    599994/599994    Array#delete_at
                   1.25   1.25   0.00    0.00    100001/1339989   Kernel#nil?
                   1.14   1.14   0.00    0.00    100001/300003    Array#size
                   1.01   1.01   0.00    0.00    100001/300002    Fixnum#>
```

Comment: Dividing 2,199,978 by 25000 (milliseconds) yields ~87 milliseconds per operation. This seems slow to me (even for Ruby), for a simple increment operation. Is that really all that's going on in this test? What happens if you do `i = i+1` instead of using the `+=` operator?

Comment: @SunilD. It's 87 calls per ms, which is still kind of slow, but it makes sense given that it's being profiled.  Nothing seems strange here to me other than someone asking if that's normal. My answer: yes, it's normal.

Comment: @DarshanComputing, good point! I've never profiled in Ruby, but when I do it in AS3 everything is terribly slow. Not sure why that didn't occur to me. Also, I didn't see that it was calls/ms, maybe I need more coffee :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results don't say `+=` takes 25 seconds.  They say that 2199978 calls to `+` took 24.59 seconds, which comes to 89.5 calls per ms.  That's a bit slow, but probably only because it's being profiled.  I don't see anything unusual in that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was launching the ruby program with ruby-prof  so much that I forgot to compare how long it takes without the profiler. When I ran the program without ruby-prof the program completed under 30 secs.